# error while install CUDA 10 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, package-management, dependencies, cuda

sudo apt install -y cuda

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
cuda is already the newest version (10.2.89-1).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-cuda-toolkit : Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev (= 9.1.85-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

sudo apt install -y libcudnn7 libcudnn7-dev libnccl2 libc-ares-dev

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-ares-dev : Depends: libc-ares2 (= 1.14.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-cuda-toolkit : Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev (= 9.1.85-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

```
nvidia-smi
Tue Dec 24 16:05:30 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.33.01    Driver Version: 440.33.01    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro M2000        On   | 00000000:03:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 56%   44C    P0    21W /  75W |    563MiB /  4040MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1531      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           144MiB |
|    0      1724      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         126MiB |
|    0      2104      G   /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/TeamViewer             20MiB |
|    0      2607      G   ...c2-865c-32f666118a2f, --gpu-preferences   265MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

what is problem while installing ?

Comment: run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` to fix the dependency issues

Comment: I did it but nothing happen

Comment: You have some dependencies on libc-ares2 , to install it run `sudo apt install -y libc-ares2`. Here is well explained [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/Mahedi-61/2a2f1579d4271717d421065168ce6a73#file-cuda_10-0_installation_on_ubuntu_18-04) on how to install cuda 10 on Ubuntu 18.04